# automatically resizing div containers CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with 2 columns with a width of 50% and a minimum width of 500px. Now what I want to know is how to get them to resize so that when the 2nd column repositions to underneath the first, the first column resizes to fill the entire page. I can't get my head around it and any help would be much appreciated. Below is the basic code:

html:

```
<div class="column">
    <div id="item-1">
        ##
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div id="item-2">
        ##
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.column{
    width:50%;
    min-width:500px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Your min-width is 400px. Modify your css or your description to keep the consistency of this question.

Comment: sorry i hadn't realised i will change it now, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .column { width: 100%; float: none; }
}
```

Tweak that and you should get what you want.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as "Answer" if it answered the question! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a media query:

```
@media all and (max-width:1000px) {
  .column {width:100%;}
}
```

Comment: if this solution worked for you, you should mark it answered to give the person credit.